# How to brodcast discover a webserver on a special port

Tags: c#, .net, networking, maui, iot

I have a webserver running on a raspberry pi on port 7299, and I also have a .NET MAUI app which I want to discover the raspberry pi webserver from. The raspberry is kind of an IoT where I want to exchange some data between, how can I discover the device in a smart and fast way?

I have tried googling around and asked GPT, but I cannot figure out a smart way. I first tried a for loop with all the addresses in the network, but its really slow. I read somewhere that you maybe could do a "brodcast" and discover the device but I cannot figure out how to do it.

If it helps the webserver on the raspberry pi is running a docker container with a .NET MVC/API project.

Thanks for all ideas and help!

Best regards Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it the best way I could, and I think it works pretty fast, this is my current solution if no one else has a better idea:

```
public async Task DiscoverDeviceAsync()
        {
            string networkRange = "10.10.0.1-10.10.0.254"; 
            int port = 7299; 

            string[] ipRange = networkRange.Split('-');
            IPAddress startIPAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ipRange[0]);
            IPAddress endIPAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ipRange[1]);

            var tasks = new Task[endIPAddress.GetAddressBytes()[3] - startIPAddress.GetAddressBytes()[3] + 1];

            for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
            {
                byte[] ipBytes = startIPAddress.GetAddressBytes();
                ipBytes[3] += (byte)i;
                IPAddress currentIPAddress = new(ipBytes);
                tasks[i] = ScanIPAddress(currentIPAddress, port);
            }

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }

        async Task ScanIPAddress(IPAddress ipAddress, int port)
        {
            try
            {
                using TcpClient tcpClient = new();
                tcpClient.SendTimeout = 100;
                await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(ipAddress, port);
                Console.WriteLine($"Web server found at IP address: {ipAddress}");
                WebServerIp = ipAddress.ToString();
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh dear me! I can't believe no one has answered this already, poor soul, that's painful what you had to do.

Ok, the thing that you are looking for is ZeroConf mDNS or also known as Bonjour.

I have no idea what ".NET MAUI" is but I use it with Node.js, Swift, Objective C, C++, Arduino to name a few and it works and that's what it's for.

Very simplified explanation:

It's basically a protocol that enables a device to broadcast its IP, port, protocol it supports (i.e. tcp, udp or something you've made up) and it's name on the local network, the router picks that up and assigns it kinda a domain name usually a ".local"

If any other device/client asks the router what's around that supports let say tcp it will get a list where your PI would be listed as for example "myPI.local"

You can then just contact your PI server on myPI.local and the router will send the request to the correct port or you can resolve that yourself including the local IP

If you know exactly what your PI will call itself you can simply target it's name and don't bother scanning the network for anything else, easy test is to type the address in the browser.

Important though, people get confused thinking that Bonjour/mDNS is a communication protocol and tend to ask questions "how to I send something over Bonjour..."
It's only a discovery thingy that enables you to have a web like domain assigned to a device like ".local" so it doesn't matter what IP your device has the router will resolve it for you.

That's it, normally in most languages it's a one line of code to start the broadcast on the "server" and then on the client side you either do a scan until you find what you want or if always the same name just hit it direct.

Hope this helps